# Knockout 3.2 amd components not updating observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I am having trouble getting observable arrays to update using knockout 3.2 with components and require. I can manually push items into the array in the view model at declaration no problem, however when they are pushed in via an ajax call OR via a hard coded push on a button click the DOM does not update.

Debugging, I can see the array has the items in, however the DOM is not updating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Default.html

```
<!-- ko if: state() === 'home' -->
    <template></template>
<!-- /ko -->
```

### Template.html

```
<table id="items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items()">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: CategoryName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: '£' + Cost"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Startup.js

```
var appStateViewModel = {
    isRunning: ko.observable(false),
    state: ko.observable('home'),
    allowLog: false
};

// Configure requirejs
require.config({
    paths: {
        text: 'Scripts/text',
        knockout: '//localhost:2222/Scripts/Plugins/knockout'
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});

// Register knockout components
ko.components.register('template', { require: './Modules/Template/Template' });

// Apply bindings for state
var scope = document.getElementById('app');
ko.applyBindings(appStateViewModel, scope);
```

### Template.js

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./Template.html'], function (ko, htmlString) {
    function TemplateViewModel(params) {

        var self = this;
        self.Items = ko.observableArray();

            $.getJSON("Items")
                .done(function (response) {

                    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                        self.Items.push({
                            Id: item.Id,
                            Name: item.Name,
                            Description: item.Description,
                            Cost: item.Cost,
                            CategoryName: item.CategoryName
                        });
                    });
                })
                .fail(function (listResponse, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                });
    }

    // Return component definition
    return { viewModel: TemplateViewModel, template: htmlString };
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce in a fiddle like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gxpjm06d/ ? Without require.js in this case. Since, there is a `template` element [implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) in some browsers already, I changed the name to `my-template`.

Comment: I can't get js fiddle to support the containerless control flow which I am using.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Does that show the flow?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't get jsfiddle to support the containerless syntax I am using  to load the control. One thing that does jump out in your example is that you are applying bindings. I am not doing this explicitly, as all of the examples in knockout's new component documentation do not have any applyBindings calls. They do seem to work to a certain extent without this call. As I am working with an amd pattern I am not sure where I would put this apply bindings call, particularly so that it is scoped to purely to this component. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, just got your update. Will take a look :)

Comment: There has to be at least an initial applyBindings call for it to work. The components work by being bound using the same mechanism as other bindings. Hope that helps!

Comment: You are right, there does need to be an apply bindings call, even if the view model bound is nothing to do with the component. I can get my code working without require no problem, however as soon as i use require for amd it does not work. This is quite frustrating as i was using this to componentise my project :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a fix. It appears I had not set up require properly.

The fix:

```
require(["knockout", "jquery", "text"], function (ko) {

    // Register knockout components
    ko.components.register('template', { require: './Modules/Template/Template' });

    // Apply bindings for state
    var scope = document.getElementById('app');
    ko.applyBindings(appStateViewModel, scope);

});
```